# Converting Varchar to Datetime for Stored procedure input

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use a `datetime` parameter in a stored procedure, in T-SQL, that if NULL will revert to `12/31/9999`.

My code looks like this:

```
EXEC abc.someStoredProc @i_param1, @i_param2, ISNULL(@l_Termination_date, '12/31/9999')
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@l_Termination_date'

I've tried using convert and cast (for example:

```
 ISNULL(@l_Termination_date,CAST('12/31/9999' AS datetime))
```

but can't seem to get it right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass variables or literals as arguments to execute a stored procedure, (or call one of a *few* specific functions), but what you can't do is have arbitrary expressions.

Move it to a separate step:

```
SET @l_Termination_date = ISNULL(@l_Termination_date,'99991231')
EXEC        abc.someStoredProc
        @i_param1
      , @i_param2
        ,@l_Termination_date
```

(Or use a separate variable if you don't want to overwrite `@l_Termination_date`)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE      @l_Termination_date DATE ; 
SET @l_Termination_date = ISNULL(@l_Termination_date,'12/31/9999')
EXEC   dbo.USP_abc.someStoredProc (
@i_param1
, @i_param2
,@l_Termination_date )
```